# Shared validation logic over two different models

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, c#-4.0, mvvm

**Update:** I've been fiddling around with a solution and I'm not quite sure if we can even do it this way. I will update the question as soon as I have a better understanding of what I want :-)

---

Our current project uses WPF along with the MVVM approach. Our application will have several editors, each with its own model.

The view will look like this:

[image: Overview]

Each editor has its own model/viewmodel/model. The parent view's (which holds all sub editors) model contains the data from which all sub editors can be feeded.

Since the user should be able to save its current state at any time, we need to be able to validate the existing data as well (because the user might have entered invalid data). So we need the validation in two places:

- when the user enters data
- when the data is loaded again after starting the application

Since we do not want to convert the data into each sub editor model just to get the validation result, the parent model should be able to be validated as well.

The only way I found to achieve this, is to introduce interfaces which basically describes the structure of the data within the class which is to be validated. It might look like this:

```
interface IValidateModel
{
  string foo;
}

class Editor1Model : IValidateModel
{
  string foo;
  int someOtherProperty;
}

class Editor2Model: IValidateModel
{
  string foo;
  byte fooBar;      
}

class ParentModel
{
  Sub subProp;
  // some other parent model properties
}
```

Once disadvantage is that now the way the data is structured is defined by the interface.

Does anyone have some experience with that problem or does even have a better solution for this?

Comment: I am not english native speaking, so probably this is the reason why I cannot completely understand your question. Can you post a more concrete/actual example/code, please?

Comment: How are you doing your validation?

Comment: The interface that you call `IValidateModel` already exists in WPF and it is named `IDataErrorInfo`. By using it you can delegate the validation to the Model (no matter how many ViewModels you have). You can read a good [tutorial here on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784331/WPF-MVVM-Validation-ViewModel-using-IDataErrorInfo) about `IDataErrorInfo` validation. Maybe it can be suitable for your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the user's input, then you should use [ValidationRules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the bindings.

You define them by inheriting from `ValidationRule` and overwriting `Validate()`:

```
public class TestRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string test = value as string;

        if (text == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "only strings are allowed");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML you specify the namespace of the validation rules:

```
<Window xmlns:vr="clr-namespace:MyApp.ValidationRules"></Window>
```

And then you can use it on bindings like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyPath">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <vr:TestRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```